# Cannot open the output file generated from running an exe

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have to run an exe file through C# code and open the output file generated by the exe to do some pre-processing.

The output file is generated successfully by running the exe. But when I try to open the output file at the same run, I am getting File Not Found Exception but when I run the program again, the code reads my output file and I am able to do the pre-processing.

```
private static void launchExe()
{
    string filename = Path.Combine("//myPathToExe");
    string cParams = "argumentsToExe";
    var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, cParams);
    proc.Close();
}
```

I now need to open the output file generated by the exe.

```
private static void openOutputFile()
{
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("//PathToOutputFile");
    string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

    /*
     * Pre Processing Code
     */            
}
```

At this stage I am getting File Not Found Exception but I have the output file generated in the specified path.

Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: the exe probably has a lock on the file that it created.  do you have the source code for the 'exe'?

Comment: Are you making sure to wait for the program to finish running? Otherwise the file might indeed not exist at the time you try to open it.

Comment: When I run the code second time,the code reads the output file from the location.The issue is I am not able to read the output file in a single run(first time alone)

Comment: @Dirk The Code run exits throwing File Not Found Exception

Comment: @Maha how are you calling these methods ? can you share that code as well

Comment: Have a look at:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande I am calling these methods in main method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't close your app, but [WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
string filename = Path.Combine("//myPathToExe");
string cParams = "argumentsToExe";
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, cParams);
proc.WaitForExit();
```